# Access denied for user (1044) - Django & MariaDB

Tags: python, django, mariadb

Trying to run some simple queries against a remote MariaDB instance. (Note: I'm not trying to apply models etc.)

I've quadruple checked spellings and I can connect with other applications on the same user/pass/port/hostname etc.

But whenever I try to run a query I get:

```
(1044, "Access denied for user 'xyz_user'@'%' to database 'xyz_name'")
```

I find the `'xyz_user'@'%'` part a little strange, I would assume it's meant to look like: `'xyz_user'@'xyz_name'`...

setings.py:

```
'xyz_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'xyz_name',
    'USER': 'xyz_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'xyz_pass',
    'HOST': 'xyz_hostname',
    'PORT': '1234',
}
```

Views module:

```
from django.db import connections

...

def some_func():
    cursor = connections['xyz_db'].cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT user FROM xyz_table LIMIT 2")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row
```

Any insight as to what I might be doing wrong is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you grant xyz_user permissions to xyz_name?

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned, I can login and run queries from other applications, i.e. MySQL Workbench. I'm double checking connectivity now - although the errors indication permissions, they don't seem to be the issue, and I'm connecting from Workbench via a different machine than the Django host.

Comment: I interpreted other applications to mean other databases as well.

Comment: No worries. It doesn't seem to Python specific anyway. Either it's permissions or firewall. Will comment when I've resolved it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem (user error, of course...)

For the key/value `'NAME' : 'xyz_name'` I had mistakenly added the 'Connection Name', not a database name. In this case there is only one database on this host.

Therefore:

```
'xyz_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'xyz_name',
    'USER': 'xyz_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'xyz_pass',
    'HOST': 'xyz_hostname',
    'PORT': '1234',
}
```

Should have been:

```
'xyz_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': '',
    'USER': 'xyz_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'xyz_pass',
    'HOST': 'xyz_hostname',
    'PORT': '1234',
}
```